# SQL Conditional Join on Columns

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements

There are three tables:

```
Clearance:  CLEARANCE_ID, ZONE, LOC
Zone:       ZONE, ZONE_DESC
Location:   LOC, LOC_DESC
```

I have the following query.

```
Select * from RC.CLEARANCE_ID, RC.TYPE, RC.ZONE, R.ZONE_DESC, RC.LOC, L.LOC_DESC
FROM CLEARANCE RC, ZONE R, LOC L
```

The value of RC.TYPE is 0 for zone, 1 for location.

I want ZONE_DESC (from zone table) to appear if the RC.TYPE = 0  and 
LOC_DESC to appear from LOC table if the RC.TYPE = 1

If I join CLEARANCE table with both the other tables, if doesn't bring records as one of the fields (ZONE or LOC) is null in every case.

How to I do this query?

Eg:

```
CLEARANCE ID  TYPE  ZONE  ZONE_DESC  LOC   LOC_DESC
   3           0     10    ZONE1     null     null
   4           1    null   null       50    Location1
```

Comment: That's kind of what `left join` is for.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT c.clearance_id
    , c.type
    , DECODE(c.type, 0, z.zone, 1, l.loc) zone_loc
    , DECODE(c.type, 0, z.zone_desc, 1, l.loc_desc) zone_loc_desc
FROM clearance c
LEFT JOIN zone z ON (c.type = 0 AND c.zone = z.zone)
LEFT JOIN location l ON (c.type = 1 AND c.loc = l.loc)
```

Comment: There's no `IF` in Oracle SQL.

Comment: Thanks, replaced with `DECODE`